# How to view which packages /files where updated last and when, is there a list online?

Tags: package-management, updates, update-manager, lts

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm trying to find out which packages and files where updated/changed last and when on a machine, also is there a list online that says which packages are the latest for an LTS and what was changed?

I know about

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "\ install\ "
```

and it gives me

```
2021-08-03 11:30:12 install libjcat1:amd64 <none> 0.1.3-2~ubuntu20.04.1
2021-08-03 11:30:18 install libllvm12:amd64 <none> 1:12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.3
```

It doesn't give me all the individual files that changed.  I just did an update and there were about 20 files that were installed.  Is this the right command and is there a list online I can double check against?

Thanks

Comment: You could do `dpkg -L ` on the package names, and look at the files in `/var/log/apt`. Also, you have a Useless Use of `cat`, `grep -w install /var/log/dpkg.log` instead.

Comment: @waltinator thanks do you know the site where they say what changed in these files?

Comment: See https://packages.ubuntu.com, then navigate to package Changelog. File-level is not available AFAIK.